# ubuntuMATE forgets "Always on Visible Workspace" setting on titlebar randomly

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, titlebar

I switched from xfce to MATE about 2 months ago and really like it. However, the menubar option to keep a window on visible workspace stops working randomly on different windows.

For example, with Thunderbird, I will right-click on the titlebar, select "Always on Visible Workspace" and the option will function as expected for an undetermined amount of time (few hours, few days). Once it's selected, I can scroll through my workspaces and the window sticks. Eventually, I will switch workspaces and it won't be there. I have to go to the workspace it is at and re-select "Always on Visible Workspace."

I can't seem to find folks with the same issue and i've never had sticky windows ever be an issue.

Any hints in the right direction or anything would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: This has been reported as this Launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/metacity/+bug/664943